# Java: unary if - npe

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

Why does this code can cause a NPE? Findbugs give me the hint, that this can occur and it does sometimes :-)

Any ideas?

```
public Integer whyAnNPE() {
    return 1 == 2 ? 1 : 1 == 2 ? 1 : null;
}
```

Comment: this is not Java - what language is it?

Comment: still it is not java, but now it is obvious why it gives you NPE "sometimes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: The code in the question wasn't present when I wrote this answer.

Here's another method to make it slightly clearer:

```
public static Integer maybeCrash(boolean crash) {
    return true ? (crash ? null : 1) : 0;
}
```

The important point is that we have *two* conditional expressions here. The inner one is of type `Integer` due to the last bullet point in the determination of the type as specified in [section 15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25).

At that point, we've got a situation like this:

```
public static Integer maybeCrash(boolean crash) {
    Integer tmp = null;
    return true ? tmp : 0;
}
```

Now for the *remaining* conditional expression, the previous bullet point applies, and [binary numeric promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#170983) is performed. This in turn invokes [unboxing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190699) as the first step - which fails.

In other words, a conditional like this:

```
condition ? null-type : int
```

involves potentially boxing the `int` to an `Integer`, but a conditional like this:

```
condition ? Integer : int
```

involves potentially unboxing the `Integer` to `int`.

---

**Original answer**

Here's a rather simpler example which is actually valid Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = args.length == 0 ? 1 : null;
    }
}
```

This is effectively:

```
int tmp;
if (args.length == 0) {
   tmp = 1;
} else {
   Integer boxed = null;
   tmp = boxed.intValue();
}
```

Obviously the unboxing step here will go bang. Basically it's because of the implicit conversion of a null expression to `Integer`, and from `Integer` to `int` via unboxing.

Comment: I don't see how that's applicable here. He's returning an `Integer` object, so the null won't be unboxed anyhow? He'd have to assign it to an `int` in which case the function isn't the part with the bug (I mean returning null from a method that returns an Integer is perfectly fine imo)

Comment: @Voo: No, because the type of the conditional expression is still int - it's then getting boxed again. The code in the question wasn't present when I answered - I'll edit now.

Comment: @Voo: See if it makes any more sense now :)

Comment: Yep even your comment made it somewhat clear - but my understanding was still not clear because I'd have thought that `false ? 1 : null` would exhibit the same behavior. The cited language spec and example clears up that too - thanks I appreciate it :D Always nice to learn some of the intricate corner cases of a language.

Comment: @Voo: I wasn't sure myself until I looked it all up :)