# Why does an inline conditional in Java auto-cast numbers?

Tags: java

In the following inline conditionals, one might expect an integer and a double to be printed, respectively:

```
System.out.println(true ? 0 : 0.0);
System.out.println(false ? 0 : 0.0);
System.out.println(true ? new Integer(0) : new Double(0.0));
System.out.println(true ? 0 : "");
```

Instead they are both printed as doubles when occurring together:

```
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0
```

Why are numbers auto-cast when occurring with other numbers in inline conditionals?

**Edit**: If this is occurring because `System.out.println` is overloaded what is the case for:

```
list.add(true ? 0 : 0.0);
list.add(false ? 0 : 0.0);
list.add(true ? new Integer(0) : new Double(0.0));
list.add(true ? 0 : "");
System.out.println(list);
```

outputs:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why are numbers auto-cast when occurring with other numbers in inline conditionals?

The conditional expression has to have a single result type, and that type is used to determine which overload of `System.out.println` to use. Overloads are always determined at compile-time, and it would be *really* awkward for the compiler to take two completely separate paths for an expression depending on which condition was picked.

If you *want* to do two different things based on a condition, use an `if`. If you want to pick between two values, with *one* result type, based on a condition, then the conditional operator is perfect.

EDIT: The interesting case here, IMO, is the third one. The compiler *could* have chosen to not perform any conversions, and just call `println(Object)`. To show that it's *not* doing that, here's a separate test:

```
Object x = true ? new Integer(0) : new Double(0.0);
System.out.println(x.getClass());
```

This prints out `class java.lang.Double` - and if you look at the bytecode, you'll see it's unboxing the `int` then reboxing it as a `Double`. For the gory details of how it's all determined, see [section 15.25 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: I have a question I bet Jon Skeet doesn't know the answer to.  "Is there anything Jon Skeet doesn't know the answer to??"  Seriously this is so obscure, and I ....I'm just at a loss for words that you know this off the top of your head.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but does this also apply to my updated example?

Comment: @GarrettHall - This doesn't have to do with `System.out.println` and whether it has overloads, but that "the conditional expression has to have a single result type" to quote the answer.

Comment: @Amir If you think *this* is obscure, you really would want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808117/java-unary-if-npe).

Answer (score 4):

Both sides of a conditional operator must be compatible in order to participate in the same ternary operation. According to [Java Language Specification 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), in your case

> binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

Generally, there is a long list of rules the language follows to arrive at the result type of the ternary conditional operator. Please read the language specifications if you need more details.

Comment: @KevinWelker That's exactly the part that I quoted, omitting the irrelevant parts about bytes, shorts, etc.

Comment: oops, sorry, deleted my longish comment to keep this cleaner

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Because `println` is overloaded.  It has to resolve to one of the forms, and it chooses the smallest type that captures both (int and double for the 1st 2 examples) :
`void  println(double x)`

Comment: The type of the conditional expression is determined separately from which overload is used. The compiler works out the type of the conditional expression, *then* determines which overload to pick. In the first three cases the type of the conditional expression is `double`, so `System.out.println(double)` is chosen. In the last case, `println(Object)` is chosen.

Comment: Should have said: "I stand corrected.  I forgot that "Floating-point literals in Java default to double precision.".  Otherwise I was trying to get at the same point, but much less precisely.  You are king."

Comment: No, we weren't saying the same thing - because `println` being overloaded is somewhat irrelevant, as shown by the code in my edit. The results would be the same even if only `println(Object)` existed.

Comment: I was going to add a defense of what was in my head vs my inadequate answer, but now I see that even the inside-my-head answer was inadequate.  It has nothing to do with selecting the proper overloaded version, and _everything_ to do with determining the single conditional result before it even bothers looking to see that there are optional overloaded forms of println to resolve.  Which was pretty much what you said the first time :-)

Answer (score 0):

The common type is used. 0 can be lossless converted to double. The result of (cond) ? res1 : res2 has to be of one return type.